# Create vagrant box from existing OS

Tags: clone, vagrant, virtualbox, box

Is it possible to create vagrant box using working PC or server?

lets say I am running ubuntu 12.04. It contains variety of software (with different versions)

Can I create a vagrant box using that. I mean create vagrant box using existing PC.

Not downloading from anywhere. just make a copy of current OS and share with others.

then others can boot up same copy of my pc

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by creating a physical to virtual image of your current machine. After that you need to import that image into your provider and create Vagrant box.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/566768/an-image-of-my-server-for-use-with-vagrant) for more details.